# Merge arrays of objects in json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "stores": [ 
        {
          "name" : "My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "My other store",
          "location" : "NY"
         }
     ],
  },
  {
    "stores": [ 
        {
          "name" : "Another My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Some Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "Secondary store",
          "location" : "NY"
         }
     ],
  }
]
```

I want to combine the data so it is :

```
[
        {
          "name" : "My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "My other store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         {
          "name" : "Another My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Some Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "Secondary store",
          "location" : "NY"
         }
]
```

I started with a loop but I dont know how can I group all of them into 1:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "stores": [ 
        {
          "name" : "My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "My other store",
          "location" : "NY"
         }
     ],
  },
  {
    "stores": [ 
        {
          "name" : "Another My store",
          "location" : "NY"
         },
         { 
          "name" : "Some Other store",
          "location" : "FL"
         },
         {
          "name" : "Secondary store",
          "location" : "NY"
         }
     ],
  }
];

let grouped = []
input.forEach(item => {
    const store = Object.keys(item.stores)
  console.log(store)
})
```

Comment: Instead of an array (of one object) as your output you'd probably find an object easier to deal with `{ stores: [{ ... }]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
function mergeStores(array) {
  // Convert each element to its 'stores' array, then flat all of them
  return array.flatMap(element => element.stores);
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function mergeStores(array) {
  return array.flatMap(element => element.stores);
}

const input = [
    {
        stores: [
            { name: 'My store', location: 'NY' },
            { name: 'Other store', location: 'FL' },
            { name: 'My other store', location: 'NY' }
        ]
    },
    {
        stores: [
            { name: 'Another My store', location: 'NY' },
            { name: 'Some Other store', location: 'FL' },
            { name: 'Secondary store', location: 'NY' }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(mergeStores(input))
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, btw is it possible to just store them as objects instead of an array of object?

Comment: @RainMan Like what? Please edit the question to include the desired result.

Comment: I updated the question to show how the result would look better, so remove the stores array

Comment: @RainMan Edited (or rather rollbacked). Check to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const input = [
  {
    stores: [
      {
        name: "My store",
        location: "NY",
      },
      {
        name: "Other store",
        location: "FL",
      },
      {
        name: "My other store",
        location: "NY",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    stores: [
      {
        name: "Another My store",
        location: "NY",
      },
      {
        name: "Some Other store",
        location: "FL",
      },
      {
        name: "Secondary store",
        location: "NY",
      },
    ],
  },
];

// Create the result object the way you wanted
const result = [{stores: []}]
// Loop through the input array objects
input.forEach(object => {
  // For each object, access its `stores` property and 
  //  push its contents into `result[0].stores`
  result[0].stores.push(...object.stores);
})
console.log(result);
```